# Entity object property with a timestamp/rowversion field?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 and i have a base entity called EntityBase, very simple as so

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntityBase
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Each of my entities inherit from this.  Now some entities need audit information, so i have first created an interface called IAudit

```
public interface IAudit
{
    Audit Audit { get; set; }
}
```

And the Audit object like so

```
public class Audit
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }

    public long? DeletedByUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public long CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public long UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

And if an entity needs audit information, i apply this interface.  Here is an example

```
public class Attachment : EntityBase, IAudit
{
    #region IAudit

    public Audit Audit { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am using code first, so now in my DbContext, i have this in my OnModelCreating method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AttachmentConfig());
}
```

Here is my AttachmentConfig file, which inherits from EntityBaseConfig, both included below

```
public abstract class EntityBaseConfig<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public EntityBaseConfig()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    }
}

class AttachmentConfig : EntityBaseConfig<Attachment>
{
    public AttachmentConfig()
        : base()
    {
        this.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsRequired();

    }
}
```

Now when my table is created, the Attachment table has the columns i would expect, but Audit_RowVersion is varbinary(max) instead of timestamp.

I have tried to put this line in each config file but get this error.

```
this.Property(e => e.Audit.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
```

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (36,14) : error 2039: The
>   conceptual side property 'RowVersion' has already been mapped to a
>   storage property with type 'rowversion'. If the conceptual side
>   property is mapped to multiple properties in the storage model, make
>   sure that all the properties in the storage model have the same type.

But i do not want to write this line in each file anyway.  How can i get the Audit.RowVersion column to generate as a timestamp, and ideally write it once, so that all objects that implement IAudit also get the configured fields?

EDIT:

I have now added a config file for the Audit object, which looks like this

```
public class AuditConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Audit>
{
    public AuditConfig() : base()
    {
        this.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
            .IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

And i call this in the OnModelCreating method, like so, before the other Configuration calls

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AuditConfig());
```

Now when i run my project, i get the following error

> A table can only have one timestamp column. Because table 'Attachment'
>   already has one, the column 'Audit_RowVersion' cannot be added.

If i look at the database and Attachment table created so far, it has the fields in the Audit object, but they do not have the Audit_ prefix?  Maybe this is a clue to someone?

Comment: Show your `Audit` class

Comment: Sorry my mistake, added now

Comment: You need to configure your `RowVersion`. For example: `this.Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsRowVersion()`.

Comment: this.Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsRowVersion()
doesnt exist?

Comment: You need to call it on `EntityBaseConfig<Audit>`. Add one if you don't have it already

Comment: Updated question....still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataAnnotations.

In your model class

```
public class Audit
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }

    public long? DeletedByUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public long CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public long UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [TimeStamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

You can add [TimeStamp] Attribute for your variable.

Comment: If i remove the AuditConfig and try your answer, i get an error saying A table can only have one timestamp column. Because table 'Attachment' already has one, the column 'Audit_RowVersion' cannot be added.